# search for multiple keywords in the same field in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to search several key words that appear in the same database field. For example if field contains "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and someone searches for "quick" and "dog" this should be returned as a match.

so I take the search field and explode it into an array based on spaces:

`$terms = explode( " ", $this->search_term );`

Then I thought I'd throw this into a loop:

```
foreach ($terms as $key) {
    $query->andFilterWhere( [
        'or',
        [ 'like', 'item.name', $key ],
    ] );
}
```

However this isn't working, plus it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply build properly the condition parameter, e.g. :

```
$condition = ['or'];
foreach ($terms as $key) {
    $condition[] = ['like', 'item.name', $key];
}
$query->andWhere($condition);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to join the conditions by using or conditions.

```
foreach ($terms as $key) {
    $query->orFilterWhere( [
        'or',
        [ 'like', 'item.name', $key ],
    ] );
}
```

This is how you have to add another or conditions. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#orFilterWhere%28%29-detail) for further details. 
I guess there is no other ways to do this without doing for loop.